# How to prevent duplicate file entries in msi installer file?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I analyzed my .msi file in Orca and found out that some assemblies are there multiple times, inflating the size of the installer file. How can I prevent this?

The screenshot illustrates the duplicate of RestSharp.dll.

I did track down one assembly that was added in a project of my solution where it was not needed, removed it, and verified in Orca the duplicate was removed, but this procedure does not remove all duplicates.